# Usar "View" para saber que boton ha sido presionado

Tags: java, android

tengo una duda, puedo usar view para saber que boton se uso, estoy armando una calculadora y para ahorrar codigo quiero usar un solo metodo que pueda ser usado por todos los botones numericos, pero para hacer eso, primeramente tengo saber que boton fue presionado, se que debe ser con view

```
public void bunton(View view){
    String boton=view //quiero saber que boton me presiono
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es lo que dices. Cuando creas el botón, lo haces a través de un ID, cuando lo envías a la función -única- lo recuperas usando el mismo ID, en este caso a través de la función getId() de cada View.

Creamos el listener:

```
View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
  pressed(view);
 }
};
```

Se lo agregamos a los botones:

```
v.findViewById(R.id.boton_sumar).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
v.findViewById(R.id.boton_restar).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
//...y el resto de botones.
```

Y en la función:

```
private void pressed(View view){
 switch(view.getId()){
  case R.id.boton_sumar:
   //Lo que sea para sumar...
   break;
  case R.id.boton_restar:
   //Lo que sea para restar...
   break;
  case R.id.etc:
    break;
 }
}
```

Comment: muy bien, si funciono

Comment: Esta es la versión definiendo un listener para el botón, la otra es definiendo el método a llamar desde el layout (respuesta @Juangra13) ambas son correctas, excelente aportación.

Answer (score 2):

Hay algo mas sencillo y es poner en tu xml, dentro de los view que quieras capturar, un parámetro que es `android:onClick="nombre_funcion"`.

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/num_11"
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:onClick="activateNum">
```

Y en tu activity solo creas la función siguiente:

```
 public void activateNum(View v)
 {
      switch(v.getId)
      {
            case R.id.boton_sumar:
              //Operación suma...
            break;
            case R.id.boton_restar:
              //Operación resta...
            break;
           case R.id.multiplicar:
              //Operación multiplicar...
           break;

      }
 }
```

Es lo mas sencillo y donde menos código escribes.

Comment: Esto también es correcto, tal vez es menos código ya que no define un listener para el botón, pero es su versión activada desde la vista en el layout.

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor podrías probar regresando el botón:

```
public string Button(View view)
{
   Strig boton = view;
   return boton;
}
```